# Laravel manual authentication

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, laravel-5.6

I have a local server in an office that stores all of the Active Directory details for users on a network eg username, email, phone number, normal AD stuff.

I have a PHP script that uses an LDAP query to retrieve details for the currently logged in user on the internal network, thus giving access to these details for the currently logged in user.

This is also used to pre-fill the User database with users.

I then have a Laravel application which is to use these details as authentification, bypassing a standard login screen.

Currently, I send users to an internal page where they press a button that posts all the information I retrieved using LDAP to said application. When it reaches the application I store these details in the session and use them in that way.

Can I instead use these credentials within Laravel's Auth Middleware so that a user is considered logged in?

I don't feel like have all their data crammed into the session really achieves much.

I changed `Auth/LoginController` to be like this:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // The email retrieved from the POST request
        $emailAddress = $request->get('EM');
        // Try to get this user from the User table
        $currentUser = User::where('email', $emailAddress)->get()->first();

        // If the query returned something
        if ($currentUser != null)
        {
            // Login this user
            Auth::login($currentUser);

            if($currentUser = Auth::check())
            {  
                $request->session()->put('User_name', $request->get('UN'));
                $request->session()->put('Container_name', $request->get('CN'));
                $request->session()->put('Display_name', $request->get('DN'));
                $request->session()->put('Job_Title', $request->get('JT'));
                $request->session()->put('Department', $request->get('DP'));
                $request->session()->put('Office', $request->get('OF'));
                $request->session()->put('Email', $request->get('EM'));
                $request->session()->put('Phone', $request->get('DD'));
                $request->session()->put('Mobile', $request->get('MO'));
                $request->session()->put('Manager_User_name', $request->get('MUN'));
                $request->session()->put('Manager_Container_name', $request->get('MCN'));

                return view('pages.index');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "We don't know you";
            echo $user;

            var_dump(Auth::login($user));
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially I check the database of users against the data given and then manually log in the user. At this point, I then store their data in the session.

If the data is not in the users database, I would like to add them.

Is this a Controller task or a Middleware task?

An update:

Instead of using MiddleWare I used this code:

```
public function checkUserExists(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->get('EM');
        $user = User::where('email', $emailAddress)->get()->first();

        if($user->isEmpty())
        {
            // If this user was not found
            $user = User::create(
                [
                    'username' => $request->get('UN'),
                    'displayName' => $request->get('DN'),
                    'email' => $request->get('EM'),
                    'role' => $request->get('JT'),
                    'department' => $request->get('DP'),
                    'location' => $request->get('OF'),
                    'directDialIn' => $request->get('DDI'),
                    'mobileNumber' => $request->get('MO'),
                    'managedByUsername' => $request->get('MUN'),
                    'managedByDisplayName' => $request->get('MCN')
                ]
            )
        }
        else
        {
            // If this user was found update their details
            $user->update(
               [
                'username' => $request->get('UN'),
                'displayName' => $request->get('DN'),
                'email' => $request->get('EM'),
                'role' => $request->get('JT'),
                'department' => $request->get('DP'),
                'location' => $request->get('OF'),
                'directDialIn' => $request->get('DDI'),
                'mobileNumber' => $request->get('MO'),
                'managedByUsername' => $request->get('MUN'),
                'managedByDisplayName' => $request->get('MCN')
               ]
            );

            $request->session()->put('Container_name', $request->get('CN'));
            $request->session()->put('Display_name', $request->get('DN'));
            $request->session()->put('Job_Title', $request->get('JT'));
            $request->session()->put('Department', $request->get('DP'));
            $request->session()->put('Office', $request->get('OF'));
            $request->session()->put('Email', $request->get('EM'));
            $request->session()->put('Phone', $request->get('DD'));
            $request->session()->put('Mobile', $request->get('MO'));
            $request->session()->put('Manager_User_name', $request->get('MUN'));
            $request->session()->put('Manager_Container_name', $request->get('MCN'));

            // Login this user
            Auth::login($user);

            if($user = Auth::check())
            {
                return view('pages.index');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified the AuthController to get the authentication from Active Directory and if it passes, I match them to a user record in the Laravel DB and manually login in the user:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
```

I keep the permissions (admin, reports, etc.) for that user in the Laravel DB.